# Why, crystal ball? Why?

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, story

I stare deep into my crystal ball, allowing it to reflect myself, to encompass everything of who I am. Through my reflection on its surface, I gaze into its misty, murky depths, hoping to catch a glimpse of my essence, my self.

For long hours, I ponder. For long days, I stare. Eventually, in the depths of the reflection, I see a dim shadow, spiraling. What is this secret? What aspect of my soul has struggled into view?

As the shadow takes form and clambers into being, I see that is not an image but a symbol. An E? An ε? No, it is a **3**.

Mystified, unsure, I study my crystal ball further, pouring more hours, more days into the endeavor. Surely there is more I can glean, more self-knowledge I can attain. With great effort and determination, another tenebrous form swims into view. Another secret to behold.

It swirls and resolves and becomes real. Another symbol. An L? A Λ? No, a **7**.

I stare and I ponder, I ponder and I stare, but my crystal ball shows me naught but milky white. Its depths have nothing more to give. It reflects no more of my self.

*Why did my crystal ball show me a 3 and a 7, and nothing else?*

---

To clarify: The only possible numbers the crystal ball could have shown me are 3 and 7. I could not have posted this puzzle with any other numbers in the place of 3 and 7.

---

While @Amoz has given a lovely answer, I also want to nudge people towards discovering the answer I intended. Towards that end, I will give a hint.

> If you point at my name, you will see an important number.

Comment: Could it have shown them in a different order?

Comment: @Someone Nope, just this order

Comment: Following the hint it feels like it's something to do with rot13(gur hfre vq nf vg vf gjbbarrvtugfrira (guerrkfrira vf gjraglbar) ohg v pna'g chg zl svatre ba jung gur rvtug vf sbe)

Comment: rot13(guerr gb gur cbjre vf gjbbarrvtugfrira), but I don't know how (gjbbarrvtugfrira gb gur cbjre bs bar) is meant to be ruled out.

Comment: @EdMurphy Now that someone's posted the answer, let me clarify: The ball gives the rot13(cevzr snpgbevmngvba) specifically, not just a general relationship.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I try to avoid "speculative" answers ("guesses"), but given

> the date of this posting (Valentine's Day)

I think this is worth a shot...

Speculation: The crystal ball works by showing you

> Your top half (swirled/rotated) followed by your bottom half (swirled/rotated)

You are

> a HEART.  Here's a picture of you:
>  [image]
>  "aspect of my soul... into view" clues HEART as heart and soul are closely related.

For long hours, I ponder. For long days, I stare. Eventually, in the depths of the reflection, I see a dim shadow, spiraling. What is this secret? What aspect of my soul has struggled into view?

> The top half of you has struggled into view. It has also been "spiraling" - rotated 90 degrees, and looks like a '3':
>  [image: top half]

Surely there is more I can glean, more self-knowledge I can attain. With great effort and determination, another tenebrous form swims into view.

> Now you are looking at your bottom half, also rotated a bit, and looks like a '7':
>  [image: bottom half]

Why did my crystal ball show me a 3 and a 7, and nothing else?

> Because other than a 3 and a 7, there is no other way to slice a heart horizontally and form other sets of numbers when read from top to bottom.

Comment: Wow, very good! That must be it! Glad I didn't post my speculative answers though, because they weren't in the same universe as this one! haha

Comment: What an amazing answer! I am sure this has to be it even if it is not, this is the winner for me! Detailed and foolproof

Comment: Very nice answer! Although I'm thinking probably slicing it vertically can arguably give two 7's by the left half and the right half 

Comment: This wasn't what I had in mind, but it's such a beautiful answer, I can't say it's wrong. Well done!

Comment: I thought it might be this, but since the OP said that the numbers couldn't be shown in any other order, and since the given order was no better than 73, I decided that wasn't the intended answer.

Answer (score 11):

Is it possible that

> you misread the characters and that what you thought was Λ was actually ^

and that the crystal ball was actually

> giving you your puzzling.stackexchange id of 2187 by presenting 3^7

and of course it gives you this because

> it's giving you a puzzle to solve!

Comment: There were only two characters, 3 and 7 - but I think this answer still works even disregarding the first spoiler.

Comment: I agree. I'm a bit skeptical of my answer, or at least feel like I am missing something as it doesn't explain the gap between the two output characters.

Comment: This was the answer I had in mind (and I would write it rot13(ol chggvat gur 7 nobir naq gb gur evtug bs gur 3, fb ab rkgen punenpgre vf arrqrq.))

Answer (score 7):

Well, you got lucky and unlucky at the same time.
Lucky because you had a rare vision by the crystal ball
Unlucky, because it made it harder to find what was going on.

The crystal ball

> gives the prime factorization of the user id.

In your case,

> you got 3 and 7, and your id is 2187. The prime factorization of 2187 is `3^7`. (Congratulation for have such a nice factorization)

If I was too look into the crystal ball, I would see

> [2,1,29,1,1319,1]
>  Because `2^1 * 29^1 * 1319^1 = 76502` is the prime factorization of my id.

The last question is, is there a way to

> break RSA with the crystal ball ? I don't think so, you would need a lot of user to look into the ball, and from the description, it took days only to gather two numbers. The internet is safe!

Comment: This was the answer I had in mind. Well done!

Comment: Spending a few days to break an encryption is a very, very good cryptanalysis result.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the correct answer. This is one of the few sites where waiting to accept is actually frowned upon

Comment: @NoName I accepted a different answer because I liked it more, even though this one was what I'd initially imagined.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a punt, but

> your user name "I's a a CG" could mean that the crystal ball thought that you should be rendered as the 3rd and 7th letters of the alphabet?

Comment: Nope, that's not it. If this were the answer, the crystal ball would've shown C and G instead.